# can't decode JWT token

Tags: python, jwt

I receive JWT token from google oauth API. I am able to decode it via jwt.io website using RS256 algorithm. The question is how to decode it via python? I tried using pyJWT but with no luck:

```
import jwt
js = jwt.decode(
    "JWT staff",
    algorithms=["RS256"],
)
print(js)
```

I get following error:

```
jwt.exceptions.InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed
```

So, what is the issue? And how to decode received JWT?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with actual input data. Your code seems to be correct but the configuration could be wrong for your token.

Comment: Google OAuth2 id_token JWT contains sensitive information

Comment: No, seems like something wrong with my PyJWT installation. jwt.exceptions.InvalidAlgorithmError: The specified alg value is not allowed

Comment: No, I forgot some arguments. You have to provide a public key. Try this example https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#encoding-decoding-tokens-with-rs256-rsa

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't work. I think something is wrong with PyJWT dependencies

Comment: Did you install the crypto version of PyJWT?  https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

Comment: yep, pip install pyjwt[crypto]

Comment: so many things unclear in this question. 1) do you just want to decode or also verify the token?  2)  what does this first paramter "JWT staff" mean? 3) How and in which format did you pass the public key?

Comment: Try removing the array from algorithms. instead use algorithm="RS256"

Comment: @RushabhSudame why that? `algorithms=["RS256"]` is correct.

Comment: having same issue, even get_default_algorithms shows that algorithms is supported

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found an answer how to decode Google OAuth2.0 JWT id_token. Below is code I used, it only returns decoded payload.

```
import base64
import json


def parse_id_token(token: str) -> dict:
    """
    Parse Google OAuth2.0 id_token payload
    """
    parts = token.split(".")
    if len(parts) != 3:
        raise Exception("Incorrect id token format")
    payload = parts[1]
    padded = payload + "=" * (4 - len(payload) % 4)
    decoded = base64.b64decode(padded)
    return json.loads(decoded)
```

Comment: so you really just wanted to decode the token. You didn't respond to my comment above in which I asked about that. To decode you can simply call `jwt.decode(encoded, options={"verify_signature": False})`, much easier than what you do here.

Comment: Thanks, I will use your solution since it looks more elegant.

Comment: Learned a new thing today, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue,
found this https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/jwt/algorithms.py#L49,
needed to install cryptography (poetry add cryptography)

Comment: This should rather be a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
pip install pyjwt
pip install pyjwt[crypto]
```

Then run this code:

```
import jwt

token = 'your_token_here'
decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, options={'verify_signature': False})

print(decoded_token)
```